# get the return value of bat file in windows in unix?

Tags: windows, linux, bash, unix, command-line

i have the following case :-
i write bash file `bbb` in windows 2003 and but a return value = 3 by `exit  /b 3`  then i execute this bash file from unix by this command :- `ssh -l admin host 'cmd /c start c:\bbb'` but when i print the return value i get ( 0 ) not ( 3 ) i print this value by `echo $? ' now how i can get a return value "exit code" from windows bash ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your return code is being masked by `start`, you should not be using it in this case.

Comment: if i can't use `start` what i should use ?

Comment: if `bbb` is indeed a bash script, you should run it using `bash`, not `cmd`. eg, `ssh -l admin host 'bash bbb'`, or without bash if your ssh runs bash by default.

Comment: i try with bash and without anything the result is :-` bash: c:bbb.bat: No such file or directory` .... and remember i want to execute batch file in windows

Comment: is `bbb` a `bash` script or a `cmd` batch file? I'm sort of confused here. anyway, if it _is_ a batch file the previously suggested `cmd /c  c:\\bbb.bat` will work. remember to double your backslashes as they act as escape characters and will be expanded by the remote side.

Answer (score 0):

your `$?` is the return code of ssh command. I don't have a windows machine to try, you could echo the `%errorlevel%` after your `cmd` command

Comment: i try to execute command as you say `ssh -l Admin host 'cmd /c start bbb.bat && echo %errorlevel'` .... it print %errorlevel%